# Add a new element between two existing

Tags: javascript, css

I use wordpress and I would like to add with a custome way a new element in a menu between to existing.

The first has the class `.btx-navbar-header` and the second

```
#menu-main-menu
```

Here is something I tried:

```
.btx-navbar-header + #menu-main-menu::before {
    content: '<a href="www.google.com">Google it!</a>';
    display: block;
}
```

However the hyperlink is not work. Is there any way to make it work? Also the use of `display:block` makes the second element go to the next line in page.

Example of menu source.

```
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="btx-navbar-nav btx-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-99 current_page_item menu-item-144"><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160"><a href="">test3</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="">Test2</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115"><a href="">test8</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141"><a href="">Tset5</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a href="">Tset4</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143"><a href="">test0</a></li>
  <li class="btx-menu-search"><a href="#" class="js-menu-search"><i class="twf twf-search"></i></a>
    <div class="btx-navbar-search btx-p-bg-bg btx-s-text-color"><span class="btx-close-button twf twf-ln-cross"></span>
      <form class="btx-search-form" role="search" method="get" action=""><span class="btx-search-form-title twf twf-search"></span><input type="text" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s" /></form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the menu source code you are working with please? Thank you.

Comment: When using the `:after` pseudo selector, you're not inserting html...just a plain string. You'd have to enter it in your html or do so using javascript but not css.

Comment: As @CarlEdwards said, you'll have to use javascript for that. If your using jQuery, the function will look something like this: $('.btx-navbar-header').append('<a href="www.google.com">Google it!</a>');

Comment: @NewToJS I provided an example

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with the relevant `HTML` Where in this `HTML` are you wanting to append a new element?

Comment: @Architect it is possible to add js into head. Not sure for jQuery as I tried the command you mention and it is not working.

Comment: @NewToJS sorry I can understand the element is before this menu I want to add.

Comment: @Stiar Can you explain where you want to add the new element? Can you explain which element id/class is the wrapper and which two elements you wish to append between? For example: `#container` with element `#One` and element `#Two`... Append in `#container` After `#One` and but before `#Two` **=>** (Between `#One` & `#Two`).

Comment: Have you added the jquery library to your head section so you can use it? Give me a second I'll write you a raw javascript so you wont have to add any libraries.

Comment: Posted a solution with plain JS, let me know if that worked.

Comment: @Stiar are you trying to add a new `li` => **List Item** with `a` => **anchor tag** as the first menu option or in a different/specific place?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 <script>
 function addMenuItem(aText,aUrl,nextTo) {
     var menuItem = document.createElement("LI");
     var menuItemAnchor = document.createElement("A");
     var menuItemAnchorText = document.createTextNode(aText);
     menuItem.appendChild(menuItemAnchor);
     menuItemAnchor.appendChild(menuItemAnchorText);
     menuItemAnchor.href = aUrl;
     var ref = document.querySelector(nextTo);
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(menuItem, ref.nextSibling);
 }

 // This is when you call the function and give it a URL and the text for the menu. Also you specify after which LI should it append the new menu item
 addMenuItem('Google It!','http://www.google.com','li.menu-item-144');

 </script>
```

Later you can add more items to the menu onClick, window load or whatever case you need it to work. Just call the function like this:

```
 addMenuItem('Button Title','Button URL','LI Class');
```

Let me know if this helped. Also this does not require a jQuery library as this is plain JS.

Comment: This is just a script to `append()` a new element but knowing the correct location of where to append it to is still unknown, hence my comments/questions above. Also your example will append the new element `List Item` after all other child elements (At the end).

Comment: I updated the answer, the 3rd variable is to specify the LI after which the new menu item is added. Try the new code and let me know if it worked.